# Does this exchange in Captain Marvel allude to any comic events?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

In the 2019 MCU film, *Captain Marvel*, the following exchange happens between Monica Rambeau and Fury:

> Monica: Maybe I can fly up and meet you halfway.
> Fury: Only if you learn to glow, like your Auntie Carol.
> Monica: Or maybe I'll build a spaceship.
>
> <sup>*Captain Marvel* (2019)</sup>

Now, I know that in the comics, [Monica Rambeau](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monica_Rambeau) became a superhero who took the mantle of Captain Marvel at some point, so this apparently foreshadows that Monica may become a superhero at some point in the MCU.

**Does Monica Rambeau build any significant technology** in the Marvel comics?

Comment: Why does it have to allude to anything in the comics? It could be a reference to the test ship that Carol crashed in.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot it doesn't have to allude; I should rather be asking *if* it alludes.

Comment: People are quick to downvote, but I don't see anything wrong with this question.   Seems like a legitimate good question to me.

Comment: Glowing definitely alludes to her comic powers, not sure about building anything.

Comment: In the comics, Monica Rambeau exhibits no special inventor or building skills in any of the stories I have read. She was a coast guard before becomg Captain Marvel, with no academic degress AFAIR.

Comment: @Klaus is right, there's no instance of her building any significant technology in the comic books. As for the exchange itself, since she's the one who proposed flying and meeting them halfway up, she basically expanded on how she could do it in a more grounded way than becoming a superhero herself. Now that could be foreshadowing for the kind of headstrong character she'll grow up to be in the MCU, but proposing that she could fly and meet them halfway up and then having a reasonable response to Fury's retort makes for better writing than having no response.

Comment: I misread this as for the Shazam movie and thought the quote was someone speaking to the deadly sin Fury and was so confused…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No.

This sentence is more of a throwaway line, however **in the MCU** (*not* the comics) Monica goes on to become superpowered by passing through [The Hex](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Westview_Anomaly) (or [The Westview Anomaly](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Westview_Anomaly)) and also worked for [S.W.O.R.D.](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/S.W.O.R.D.), in which she may or may not have (unconfirmed **in the MCU**) designed some sort of technology. (For clarity, she was **not** involved in the design of [White Vision](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/White_Vision), which was one of S.W.O.R.D.'s more notable projects.)

Answer (score 1):

The exchange is more of a foreshadowing of Monica Rambeau’s future in the MCU than an allusion to an event in the comics.

> **Fury:** Only if you learn to glow, like your Auntie Carol.

In *WandaVision* (2021 TV series), Monica gained her powers ("learned to glow") due to exposure to the [Hex / Westview Anomaly](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Westview_Anomaly#Monica_Rambeau%27s_Disappearance).  Then, in the *WandaVision* series finale, she was [invited by Nick Fury via a Skrull, who told Monica that Fury wanted to meet with her in space](https://youtu.be/RkEtOYpB0SQ?t=50) ("fly up").

“Space” turned out to be the [S.A.B.E.R. Space Station](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/276624/7957), as revealed in the first episode of *Secret Invasion* (2023 TV series) and [*The Marvels* teaser trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuk77TjvfmE).

[image: S.A.B.E.R. Space Station][image: S.A.B.E.R. Space Station]
[image: Monica in The Marvels teaser trailer]

> **Monica:** Or maybe I'll build a spaceship.

In *Secret Invasion*, Fury said he had been “building out S.A.B.E.R.”  and President Ritson stated that “Agent Fury is building up the most complex aerospace defense system in the history of mankind” in reference to S.A.B.E.R. In a way, Monica (now working for S.A.B.E.R. in *The Marvels*) was involved in “building a spaceship”.

> **Monica:** Maybe I can fly up and meet you halfway.

In *The Marvels*, Monica will be reunited with Carol Danvers (“meet you halfway”).