# Where was Fury in the post credits scene for "Far From Home"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home, nick-fury

In the post credits scene from *Spider-Man: Far From Home* it is revealed that Fury

> was not actually Fury throughout the movie's events but Talos who was acting on Fury's orders.

The scene switches to show Fury relaxing on a beach, which turns out to be an "illusion" and then it shows that he is actually

> on a spaceship in space. It appears that it *might* be a Skrull ship.

Do we have any more information on what this was and where he was? It appeared as though he was in some official "commander" capacity, so is this a part of the remnants of S.H.I.E.L.D.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [S.A.B.E.R.](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/S.A.B.E.R.) [Space Station](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/S.A.B.E.R._Space_Station)

[image: S.A.B.E.R. Space Station screenshot from The Marvels teaser trailer]

<sup>([Image is from *The Marvels* teaser trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuk77TjvfmE))</sup>

*[Secret Invasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Invasion_(TV_series))* (2023 TV series) [S01E01 "Resurrection"](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Resurrection_(Secret_Invasion)) sheds more light on Fury’s whereabouts during the *Spider-Man: Far From Home* post-credits scene. In the episode, it was revealed that **Fury was on the [S.A.B.E.R.](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/S.A.B.E.R.) [Space Station](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/S.A.B.E.R._Space_Station)**, a project that [President Ritson](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Ritson) describes as “the most complex aerospace defense system in the history of mankind.”

The [teaser trailer for *The Marvels*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuk77TjvfmE) shows Fury inside the S.A.B.E.R. Space Station with several S.A.B.E.R. personnel:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 13):

I've had a look around and found this interview from Jon Watts, the director for *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, where he was asked this question, and whilst he wasn't specific he says it is a Skrull spaceship, they are in space and Fury is on a mission. He doesn't elaborate on this any further.

> **But where exactly is Fury?**
>
> **Watts:** It’s definitely a Skrull spaceship. But I don’t know if I can specifically say where they are. They’re in space. He’s on a mission, but he got to take a very brief vacation on this little relaxation pod.
>
> <sub>[Los Angeles Times, Spider-Man team spills secrets of ‘Far From Home’ post-credits scenes and Marvel’s future](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment/movies/la-et-mn-spider-man-far-from-home-spoilers-post-credits-marvel-20190709-story.html)</sub>

There is speculation though that this could be S.W.O.R.D. (Sentient World Observation and Response Department), a subdivision of S.H.I.E.L.D. which monitors Earth for threats from above. Considering Fury's below comment in *Captain Marvel*, it seems likely that he would have created S.W.O.R.D. after the events of the film but we just haven't seen it yet. Though, when it was created is up for speculation, considering it doesn't seem to have had any active involvement in some of the events we've seen that you'd think it would do, therefore it could have been created after *Avengers: Endgame* with the help of Carol and the Skrull.

> **Fury:** Been riding a desk for the past few years, trying to figure out where our future enemies are coming from. Never occurred to me that they'd be coming from above.
>
> <sub>*Captain Marvel*</sub>

This was even teased at in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, though it seems to have been more of a throw away reference rather than anything more. Or, this could have even given those in S.H.I.E.L.D. the idea to go ahead and create it... we don't know.

> **Jemma Simmons:** Fury never said anything about deep space outposts being developed, did he?
>
> **Phil Coulson:** There was nothing like this in his black box.
>
> **Elena 'Yo-Yo' Rodriguez:** So, wait, S.H.I.E.L.D. doesn't have a space division called S.P.E.A.R. or something?
>
> *[Couslon nods no]*
>
> **Elena 'Yo-Yo' Rodriguez:** Really? I always thought you guys had people hiding on the moon.
>
> <sub>*Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, Season 5 Episode 1, "Orientation: Part One"</sub>

Comment: It is also possible that following the events of Endgame Fury decided to take a trip with Captain Marvel to do somthing/see somthing or just to get a feel for what is out there in the galaxy that could threaten earth. I imagine this will be hinted at in Captain Marvel 2 but possibly could be the start of the Galactus arc, Fury in space could lead to discovering the silver surfer and then combined with the fantastic 4 on earth could lead to Galactus being the big bad of phases 4 and 5.

Comment: @RichardC Aye will be interesting to see where they go with it and I did hint at it being post Endgame _"therefore it could have been created after Avengers: Endgame with the help of Carol and the Skrull."_ - Stark Tower was also sold and they haven't said to who so that could be the Baxter Building. (Rumours are it's probably either that or Oscorp Tower).

Answer (score -4):

It appears ever since the 90's, S.H.I.E.L.D. saw how there could be more intergalactic threats and decided to build a Space Station. This could very well be S.W.O.R.D., which is basically the space version of S.H.I.E.L.D.

Comment: Whilst a nice theory do you have any evidence that this is the case that you could [edit] in? I also think you mean 90's since _Captain Marvel_ takes place in 1995 and Fury didn't think to look up until she came along.

Comment: I don't, sorry, and I do mean 90's. I should have definitely done some research before answering, but like it's just a post-credit scene, usually left unexplained, it mostly ends up as just rumours and theories.